# I am not getting an error but co-worker is getting Run Time Error 52

Tags: excel, vba

The sub is not pulling in her latest file, but rather a file from last week.

Additionally, where MyFile = " "; her MyFile = the name of last week's file.

It is very strange.

```
Sub NewestFile()

Do While Application.ProtectedViewWindows.Count > 0
    Application.ProtectedViewWindows(1).Edit
Loop
' ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date
    
    MyPath = ("C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\Downloads\")

    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)

    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile   

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Wait (Now + (ms * 0.000004))
    Call USEforPBIDownload
End Sub
```

Not really sure what to try to be honest.  Hoping someone can help make sense of it.

I can see her MyPath is correct.

Date is correct.

Comment: Does the created/modified date match the filename of last week file ? ie has last weeks file been modified more recently ?

Comment: No, the most recent file downloaded was the correct file.

Comment: Add a line `Debug.Print MyFile, Format(LMD, "dd mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss"), LatestFile` before `MyFile = Dir` and check that the correct files are detected.

Comment: Thank you,  I am requesting her to do this now and test.  She is away at the moment. Does it matter that she is in another time zone?

Comment: I meant to say country.  So she is in Warsaw, Poland and I am in US.

Comment: Which line has the `run time error 52`, is it `Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile` ? Comment out the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`. Presumably `ms` is a global declared elsewhere.

Comment: It says Bad File name.  Sorry she must be off for the day.  But from what I remember, it happens before open my path & latest file.

I was thinking... if she has another workbook open that is on autosave, could it be causing it to read that autosave xlsx file as the latest file possibly?

I do have Application.DisplayAlerts = False in the upper part of sub.  Are you saying I need to possibly add something to this?

Comment: So now this is the line giving error..   is there anything wrong with this?

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=wbpath & title & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM") & ".xlsx", _
                       FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook


says save failed.  But I can see where it is formatting everything accurately. i.e. renaming the workbook and .xlsx with date and time.

Comment: Is wbpath on a network drive eg OneDrive ?

Comment: Yes, one drive - sorry didnt realize comment had to be a certain length of characters on here.

Comment: the wbpath references the sharepoint documents path.  Btw, this worked for me and for the others.  When she started transferring this over to her, she has been having issues.  
If I run my old one, to my sharepoint, and my power bi, etc... everything still works fine.

Comment: I just noticed her sharepoint only allows smartdraw if i click new.  
whereas on my sharepoint I have the options of excel, pp, visio, onenote, word doc, etc... when I click new.

I also tried dragging and dropping a file in her sharepoint and it gave me the prohibited circle with line through it to not allow.